# How to run child_process on view Onclick event?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, child-process, hogan.js

I am new to Node js and am using express with hogan or moustache templating for my views.

I can use the below code in my routing files, index.js like below and it works fine.

```
/* Test Shell Execute. */
router.get('/shell', function(req, res){
  exec('ls -1', function (error, stdout, stderr) {
      result = stdout.toString().split("\n");
      res.render('shell', { 
            title: "Shell", 
        error: error, 
        stderr: stderr,
        result: result

    });
  });
});
```

What I want to do is to be able to run this and other exec command onclick events from my view.

When I try and use node require("child_process") in my view, I get a javascript undefined error. Like below.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
     <script>
      window.onload= function() {
        var exec = require('child_process').exec;
        exec('ls -lrt', function (error, stdout, stderr) {  
         });
    };
      </script>
    <title>{{ title }}</title>
    <link rel='stylesheet' href='/stylesheets/style.css' />
  </head>
  <body>
    <h1>{{ title }}</h1>
    <p>Hello from {{ result }}</p>
  </body>
</html>
```

It seems tedious to have to run all my node code from the routing file and go back and forth to my view. I am obviously making a big mistake here, but need some guidance.

Am I am able to run node code from my view? If not what is the best way to do this?

Console output:

```
ReferenceError: require is not defined      shell:6

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
      <script>
      window.onload= function() {
        var exec = require('child_process').exec;
        exec('ls -lrt', function (error, stdout, stderr) {
```

Comment: Back-end code doesn't just run in the front-end like back-end code would and yes generally it's best to keep javascript out of your views. But here without posting the error message you get it's hard to tell. But guessing either require is not defined or `require('child_process').exec` is undefined. Post any error output from your console it will help.

Comment: thanks @gillesc. I have added console out. It seems to just not get child_process, or anything else I have tried.

Comment: Based on your code: "ls -1" I assume you are trying to list the content of the folder and show that along your view, right? - In which case there are other, more simple, ways to do it. In Nodejs you can simply use the fs.readdir or fs.readdirSync methods, for example.

Comment: @Aichholzer that would still use require('fs') which also doesn't work in my .hjs views. This is just an example, I am wanting to run multiple commmands on an onclick event.

Comment: Maybe I am looking at it from the wrong side but logic should not be placed in your views at all. If you need to do some actions, then you can do them in the route handling methods and use a callback which will render the template and pass the data obtained from the logic.

Putting the logic in the view will try to execute it on the client (browser) and that is out of the scope of JS.

Comment: @Aichholzer I think your right, I have done that now and it seems to work ok. It just means passing params and var back and forth and then using the router node code to execute. It just seems a bit back and forth to me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Following up on the comments;

- Logic should not be placed in views, that goes against the whole MVC principle.
- Logic on the views will try to be executed on the client, which is -I assume- not your intention.
- As for the params being passed back and forth, you can -if you are using Express, for example- define a middleware that can take care of all the logic in on go.
- Again, in Express, you have `req` and `res` objects to which you can attach anything you like. So it should be fairly easy to achieve anything you need.

Finally; you can post some more code so we can have a better idea of what you are trying to do and we might be able to make a better suggestion.